# Make first value of password visible in form

Tags: html, css

So I have the following input from a form:
`<input type="passord" name="password" value="password">`
Naturally when I open the page, the `password` will be displayed `********`. I want it to be displayed as text only for the first time. I mean when someone enters an actual password it would appear the normal way `****`.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt e.g. as a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), so we can try to solve your problem and explain why your own attempt failed - that way you can learn something useful for your future development, as well as getting an answer to this single problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `placeholder="password"` in your `<input>` so:

```
<input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="password">
```

Working [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/zg1jz7dj/).

If you want to know more about `placeholder` and other input attributes read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-placeholder

Comment: Read this for all input  attributes : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-placeholder

Comment: Note that `placeholder` is meant to provide a hint, not a label. Important quote from the document linked in the answer:
"Note: Do not use the placeholder attribute instead of a <label> element. Their purposes are different: the <label> attribute describes the role of the form element; that is, it indicates what kind of information is expected, the placeholder attribute is a hint about the format the content should take. There are cases in which the placeholder attribute is never displayed to the user, so the form must be understandable without it."

Answer (score 0):

change type="password" into ---> type ="text".  the type attribute has a good amount of diverse uses for password, dates, images, month, number, etc. btw.

```html
<input type="text" name="password" value="password">
```

Nevermind this

Comment: Have you noticed "*only for the first time*" in OP question?

Comment: You didn't understand, I want it to be a password but only the first value to be visible.

Comment: you want it to be one by one so essentially: password123 would be entered like this ---> p ---> *a ---> **s ---> ***s and so on

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure I understood your question very well, let me know if I understood it wrongly. However, I made a small snippet using JQuery: to make the password visible I set input type to text. When the user wants to change is value (on keydown event), the type is changed to password.

```js
$('input').keydown(function() {
  $(this).attr('type','password')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="password" value="visible" />
```

Comment: You understood my question but as other people answered, a placeholder is easier to use in this case. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

**Using the placeholder attribute**

```
<input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Enter password here" />
      / Makes the    / Most used / This is text displaying in your box
      / Input type a / in forms  / ONLY when the box is empty
      / password     / to post   /
      /              / values to /
      /              / php       /
```